# How does one start VirtualBox guest machines automatically at host boot?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, systemd

There used to be a SystemV/init-compatible setup in Debian and Ubuntu, which made autostarting guests as easy as starting / stopping any other daemon. Old pages, including https://askubuntu.com/questions/404665/how-to-start-virtual-box-machines-automatically-when-booting , describe the SystemV setup.

However, it's 2016, and everyone has switched to systemd. My Debian testing using a stock VirtualBox shows only a vboxweb service. The official VirtualBox manual did not change, and the method described [there](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#autostart) fails.

What is the most common way in which SystemD users automatically boot guests when the host boots?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VBoxAutostart](https://github.com/Jetchisel/VBoxAutostart), which is designed to help autostart VMs using systemd.

Follow the examples, using your vm names instead of the `foo` value shown in the examples.